# Removing listeners from property in ScalaFX

Tags: scala, scalafx

I'm struggling with removing an event listener from `Property` in ScalaFX.

**Simplified example**

```
import scalafx.Includes._

object ListenerApp {

  val prop = DoubleProperty(0)

  val listener = (source, oldValue, newVal) => {
    println("Listener working, and the value is " + newVal)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    prop.addListener(listener)
    prop.value = 1
    prop.removeListener(listener)
    prop.value = 2
  }

}
```

The result is not as expected:

```
Listener working, and the value is 1.0
Listener working, and the value is 2.0
```

I've seen similar code work in JavaFX however my adaptation might be wrong.

**Addinational information**

I'm puzzled whether there's an error in my methodology, as similar thing is happening with `unbindBidirectional()`, or perhaps it is a bug since this feature might not be utilized much and nobody noticed.

Tried using a debugger to access listeners in the `delegate` but it does not display any fields.

**Why do I even need this**

I have a view displaying some `insideProp: Property`, which is a member of an object `content: T` inside a different `outsideProp: ObjectProperty[T]`.

However I don't want to display a particular `content`'s `insideProp` or rather whatever is inside the `outsideProp`. For this I need a removable binding, or an removable event listener as the view should only be modified by the current content of `outsideProp`.

I would gladly create a new "immutable" view for every `content` however speaking from experience `JavaFX` isn't really build for this behaviour, and there is also a problem of memory leaks.

*I would much appreciate somebody pointing what I'm doing wrong.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Adding a Listener

The idiomatic way of adding property listeners in ScalaFX is to use the
`onChange` method:

```
val prop = DoubleProperty(0)

prop.onChange { (source, oldValue, newValue) =>
  println(s"Property $source changed value from $oldValue to $newValue")
}
```

If you just want the new value you can ignore the first two parameters:

```
prop.onChange { (_, _, newValue) =>
  println(s"Property changed value to $newValue")
}
```

### Removing a Listener

A subscription handle lets you remove a listener.
A subscription is created for every listener added to a property.
When you no longer need to the listen, you "cancel" the subscription:

```
val prop = DoubleProperty(0)

val subscription = prop.onChange { (_, _, newValue) =>
             println(s"Property changed value to $newValue")
           }

prop.value = 1
subscription.cancel()

// Listener will not be notified about this change
prop.value = 2
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `subscription.cancel()` method. I never actually use listeners explicitly. Thanks, this changes a lot.